# Get direction not working for korean language in google maps api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having a functionality of get-direction for English language. Same functionality is not working for Korean language.

```
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places></script>
```

This is the change, rest all is fine.

```
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places&language=ko"></script>
```

While getting directions between two addresses response coming with

`status="ZERO_RESULT"`

Is it because of Korean language characters? As it is working in google maps but not using API. Any other thing to take care while working for different language.

Comment: This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/YvgN8/ . What's the encoding of your page and with which parameters you are calling the DirectionsService.

Comment: Thanks Dr.Molle, I want results for Korea region. Try to get directions within Korea.

Comment: I don't get any result for korea in any language. Looks like directions are not supported yet for Korea : http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapcoverage_filtered.html